# Input value into function in javascript

Tags: javascript, function

So i want user to input value using prompt and the value entered should go through the function and give the output

```
function isEven(a)
{


if (a%2==0) {
    console.log(a+"is true");
}
else
{
    console.log(a+"is false");
}

return a;
}

isEven(5);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your updated code:

```js
var number = prompt("Please enter your number: ")

console.log(number + ' is ' + isEven(number));

function isEven(a) {
  return a % 2; // 0 means Even and 1 means ODD
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
isEven(parseInt(prompt("Please enter your number : ")))
```